# Sorting legend items across multiple layers alphabetically

Tags: qgis, legend, sorting

Is it posisble in QGIS layout manager to sort all legend items from multiple layers/groups alphabetically after i have hidden the groups? So from layer 1 I have item A and item D, from layer 2 i have item B and item F, and from layer 3 i have item C and item E. I want the legend to show in the order item A, item B, item C, item D, item E, item F, and for the layer/group names to be hidden.